# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null in HTML and Issue of Making Button Active in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell what is the mistake in my html code, I am getting error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null" in the second line of script tag; var btns =... Also my implemented code of active header is not working. The button does not get active after clicking  ...

```
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color:#7f9cf5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  transform-style: inline-flex:;
  color : white;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}


/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #5a67d8;
  color: white;
}

</style>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function actHeader() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<header class="text-gray-700 body-font">
  <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
    <a class="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-10 h-10 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5"></path>
      </svg>
      <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" href="/index">
      <span class="ml-3 text-xl">{{ params['website_name'] }}</span>
      </a>
    </a>
    <div class="shadow sm:shadow-md md:shadow-lg lg:shadow-xl xl:shadow-2xl" id="myDIV">
    <nav class="md:ml-auto md:mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base">

      <button class="btn"><a href="/">Home</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn"><a href="/participate">Participate</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn"><a href="/entries">Entries</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn"><a href="/rules">Rules</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
      <button class="btn"><a href="/result">Result</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
      <button class="btn"><a href="/rewards">Rewards</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
      <button class="btn"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    </nav></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: The script is executed before the page is rendered. So there is no div `myDIV` when `document.getElementById("myDIV");` is called, resulting in `header = null`. Wrap it in a funtion and call when the body is loaded.

Comment: Same for the active buttons: the buttons don't exist at the time of execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael says, you're running the javascript too soon.

The easiest way to resolve this is to put the script at the bottom of the page, just before `<\body>`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //your script
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```